# Split string and map values, then join again

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I use the external data-extension to load data from an external XML-source.

One of the variables contains a string that is separated with commas, for example:

```
Apple,Banana,Orange
```

I would like to transform this string to use it in the template. The resulting string should look like:

```
[[Apple]], [[Banana]], [[Orange]]
```

The amount of values in the string is not fixed, it varies from 1 to round about 20.

How can I do this? The #explode-function only allows access to a single specific value within the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension:Arrays can do what you want, so if you can install that https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays

If you can't install extensions you'll have no choice but to use {{#explode:}}

Comment: I can install. I'll have a look! :-)

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks!